# I'm trying to hide all elements inside the array by changing width. Used setInterval inside function but it only runs correctly for the last element

Tags: javascript, for-loop, setinterval

```
function removeElements(){
    var t;
    var x = 0;
    var s;
    for(i=0; i <removeArray.length; i++){
    t = document.getElementById(removeArray[i]);
    t.innerHTML = "";
    s = parseInt(t.style.width, 10);
    var int = setInterval(function() {
      if (s <= x) { 
          clearInterval(int); 
          return;  } 
      else { 
          s-=2; 
          t.style.width = s + "px";
           }
        }, 2);
 }}
```

> For loop is going through array and removing text from elements and then hiding them by changing width inside `setInterval` until zero. Unfortunately it only makes last element in array hide close correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is because you've declared `t` and `s` outside your loop (I could add `x` but you never update its value so it doesn't matter). The callback function inside `setInterval` is executed when the loop is over (whatever the size of `removeArray` or the delay) so when it is executed `t` is always the last element `document.getElementById(removeArray[removeArray.length - 1])`

You could declare `t` and `s` inside the loop using `let` and `const`.

```js
function removeElements() {
  // var t;
  var x = 0;
  // var s;
  for (let i = 0; i < removeArray.length; i++) {
    const t = document.getElementById(removeArray[i]);
    t.innerHTML = "";
    let s = parseInt(t.style.width, 10);
    let int = setInterval(function() {
      if (s <= x) {
        clearInterval(int);
        return;
      } else {
        s -= 2;
        t.style.width = s + "px";
      }
    }, 2);
  }
}
```

Note that a better idea (IMHO) would have been to add a class to your array elements and let CSS handle the animation

Comment: Omg you are legend it works perfectly. And thanks for explanation.